# classes or wrapper for working with dde in .net?

Tags: interop, wrapper, dde

Can anyone point me to classes or wrapper to use when working with DDE in .NET?

yeah yeah, I know it's supposed to be obselete etc etc :) Just sometimes necessary to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: http://www.codeplex.com/ndde I've had to write a few DDE clients, and it was always such a pain.